# Integrating perl Editor with My Eclipse

Tags: perl, myeclipse

I had some automation scripts written in perl. 
I am able to run those scripts using Eclipse 3.x versions with the help of **epic ide**.
But I need to Integrate them with **My Eclipse 6.0** . I googled but couldn't find any plugin to match . Could anyone help me in this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to install EPIC plugin also in My Eclipse adding the repository update site, otherwise you can try with [perlipse](https://code.google.com/p/perlipse/) .